# Infinite loop when iterating over a character array

Tags: c#

The following program is going in infinite loop when I am trying to access a multiple line input,do you have any idea why is it not working?

```
namespace AlternatingCharacters
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int N = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            string[] str = new string[N];
            for (int i = 0; i < N ; i++)
            {
                str[i] = Console.ReadLine();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
            {
                int count = 0;
                Char[] strArray = str[i].ToCharArray();
                for (int j = 0; j < strArray.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (strArray[i] == strArray[i + 1])
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine(count);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit the title to include just the problem. Any other specifics / questions should be part of the post

Comment: I think you have a _bigger_ problem in here rather than infinite loop. You should learn how to debug your code. Read from Eric Lippert: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) Also from MSDN: [Debugging in Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sc65sadd.aspx)

Comment: Instead of an anonymous `i` and `j`, use `stringIndex` and `characterIndex` - the immediate problem will then be clear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
for (int j = 0; i < strArray.Length; j++)
```

Your condition is checking on `i`, not on `j`, so `i` will always be `0` (start value) and will never change during the loop.

The right code is:

```
for (int j = 0; j < strArray.Length; j++)
```

After that it will fail on this line:

```
if (strArray[i] == strArray[i + 1])
```

At the end, it can't find 'the last index + 1' which you can prevent by subtracting one on the end, so this (also I think you need `j` here):

```
for (int j = 0; j < strArray.Length - 1; j++)
{
    if (strArray[j] == strArray[j + 1])
    {
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting,I was changing some part of the code,so I got wrong in pasting it here. But even after changing i->j,its going in the indexoutofbound error. Can you give an idea on this!

Comment: The code works when I make the changes described above.

Comment: Thanks,the code works!

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from this piece of code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
{
    int count = 0;
    Char[] strArray = str[i].ToCharArray();
    for (int j = 0; i < strArray.Length; j++)
    {
        if (strArray[i] == strArray[i + 1])
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(count);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

First your loop-condition of the inner loop is whrong. While you increment `j` you check if `i` equals the number of elements in your array. More critical than this however is that you also use the whring array-elements. I guess you should use `if (strArray[j] == strArray[j + 1])` instead of using `i` as index.

So all in all this should work:

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
{
    int count = 0;
    Char[] strArray = str[i].ToCharArray();
    for (int j = 0; j < strArray.Length; j++)
    {
        if (strArray[j] == strArray[j + 1])
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(count);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```